# MethodNotAllowedHttpException na paginação laravel 5.5

Tags: paginação, laravel-5.5, csrf

Estou com problemas para fazer a paginação de dados na view. Quando realizo a busca ele retorna todos os dados, mas quando acesso o link da paginação ele retorna o erro "MethodNotAllowedHttpException".

> http://localhost:8000/buscar?page=2

Estava com o o mesmo problema na página principal de busca por causa do CSRF, mas resolvi atribuindo a rota nas exceções do VerifyCsrfToken, mas não sei como adiciono as rotas de paginação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é uma requisição POST, se for porque não utiliza GET?

Comment: Sim, é uma requisição post!

Comment: Não poderia ser um GET para montar a sua url com os dados? veja é uma complicação desnecessária (até pode fazer com post, mas, dá um pequeno trampo)

Comment: Funcionou com o metodo GET! Obrigado @VirgilioNovic.
Fiquei tão focado no erro e deixei passar os detalhes!